# how to get grails f:table working (3.3.8)

Tags: grails, grails3

grails is great, but where there is no example its very hard to use.

In my view I have:

```
<f:table collection="${bankAccountList}"/>
```

in my controller I tried as many variations as I could think of, e.g:

```
:
respond BankAccount.findAllByUser(user)
}
```

and

```
:
def bankAccounts = BankAccount.findAllByUser(user)
[bankAccountList: bankAccounts]
}
```

I also tried what is in the oficial documentation for the view:

```
 <f:table collection="bankAccountList"/>
```

The error I always get is:

```
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/dashboard/index.gsp:10] Error executing tag <f:table>: [views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp:5] Error executing tag <g:sortableColumn>: null
```

BankAccount.findAllByUser(user) is definitely returning the players bankAccount records.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using version 2.2.8 of the `fields` plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information to say for sure what is wrong but if you pass a `List` of `BankAccount` instances to the `respond` method, then in the view you will be able to use `<f:table collection="${bankAccountList}" />`.

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/johnlittletable demonstrates that.

See the use of the `f:table` tag at https://github.com/jeffbrown/johnlittletable/blob/99e6c5c36e6a1b72ab6f20552fd66e0a67767927/grails-app/views/bankAccount/index.gsp#L21.

I hope that helps.